# Multiline text on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, drawtext

So I'm trying to create a Meme generator using the HTML5 canvas. I understand I can write on the canvas using the following:

```
ctx.filltext()
```

However, I can only write on the canvas once. Does anyone know how I could write on the canvas more than once or even twice as in multiple times. As with Meme generators they have one line of text at the top and one at the bottom of the image. If it's not possible could anyone let me know or point me in the direction of a tutorial/answer that could let me write on top of an image with text including changing the font and font size plus top/bottom, left/right.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Easy. Just issue multiple `fillText` commands: `fillText('top',10,topY); fillText('bottom',10,bottomY).`

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it worked, however when I went to change the font size for the second one it changed both of them to same size. I can't seem to use an Array to create multiple filltext() either so that I could set each font size. Any ideas?

Comment: I've posted an answer showing how to create a reusable function to draw styled text. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a function that draws text given your desired styling arguments:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

drawText('This is the top',canvas.width/2,20,24,'verdana');
drawText('This is the bottom',canvas.width/2,canvas.height-20,16,'Courier');

function drawText(text,centerX,centerY,fontsize,fontface){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface;
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle';
  ctx.fillText(text,centerX,centerY);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok now I have another issue. Copied that into my file but it's reporting in the console - Type Error: canvas is null. I do not understand this at all. Any ideas??

Comment: The error is not related to `drawText`. Are you using `window.onload` to let the DOM load completely before executing your drawing commands? If not, you must do so.

Comment: I managed to solve it by putting the javascript at the bottom of the page before the </body> tag.